# what data flow transformation control to use

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I Would like to create an ssis SQL server 2008 project (BIDS) to ETL from Database DB1 (table11. Table12, table13) on a server SR1 to a server SR2 (connected via VPN connection to SR1), with destination database DB2 (table2).what are the best data flow controls to be used in the source,transformation and destination. What will be the best design possible .Both databases are on SQL server 2008.
Appreciate your input

Comment: Depends on the type of task you are performing. if it's not simple bulk insert then probably you have to go for some container to use.

Comment: Insert only or do you need updates? What sort of data volumes are we talking about? Hundreds, millions, billions? Only a single table or multiple? If multiple, is there a hierarchy? Is the destination system highly transactional? One time load or ongoing synchronization?

Comment: I cannot use bulk insert because at source I have three table and destination one table , need to do mapping and calculation to have the new results inserted into the single destination table.thank you

Comment: Hi billinkc .yes insert and update , data volume around  1millions.source three tables and destination one table.The destination environment is not transactional .the will be a SQL server job that execute the package every 24 hours